# How to replace rows in pandas dataframe with other rows in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe (`my_df`) which looks like this:

| index | event_num | recording_num | session_code | weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99378 | 11 |  |  |  |
| 99379 | 11 | 11 | P1 | clear |
| 99380 | 11 |  |  |  |
| 99381 | 4 | 4 | P2 | rain |
| 99382 | 37 | 37 | Q4 | wind |
| 99383 | 39 | 39 | Q5 | snow |
| 99384 | 4 |  |  |  |

I need to fill in the empty values in the columns `recording_num`, `session_code` and `weather` to get this end result:

| index | event_num | recording_num | session_code | weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99378 | 11 | 11 | P1 | clear |
| 99379 | 11 | 11 | P1 | clear |
| 99380 | 11 | 11 | P1 | clear |
| 99381 | 4 | 4 | P2 | rain |
| 99382 | 37 | 37 | Q4 | wind |
| 99383 | 39 | 39 | Q5 | snow |
| 99384 | 4 | 4 | P2 | rain |

Code for constructing `my_df` dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'index': np.arange(99378, 99385), 
    'event_num': [11, 11, 11, 4, 37, 39, 4],
    'recording_num': [np.nan, 11, np.nan, 4, 37, 39, np.nan], 
    'session_code': [np.nan, 'P1', np.nan, 'P2', 'Q4', 'Q5', np.nan], 
    'weather': [np.nan, 'clear', np.nan, 'rain', 'wind', 'snow', np.nan]
}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have tried `my_df.ffill(axis = 0)` but it doesn't work because ffill takes the previous observation forward which doesn't work for the last row.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How about sorting on `event_num`, applying `ffill` and then sorting again on  `index`?

Comment: What is the logic of filling?? By event_num?

Comment: Hello @DimaChubarov! This is a good idea, I have tried it and it works. But what if I do the ordering on `event_num` and the first instance of an event has nulls?? What can we do then?

Comment: Hello @gtomer! Yes, the logic is to fill any nulls with the data contained in the same `event_num`. Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `fillna`:

```
>>> my_df.fillna(my_df.groupby("event_num")[["recording_num","session_code","weather"]].ffill().bfill())

   index  event_num  recording_num session_code weather
0  99378         11           11.0           P1   clear
1  99379         11           11.0           P1   clear
2  99380         11           11.0           P1   clear
3  99381          4            4.0           P2    rain
4  99382         37           37.0           Q4    wind
5  99383         39           39.0           Q5    snow
6  99384          4            4.0           P2    rain
```

Comment: Thank you for this @not_speshal, how can I get back the `event_num` column? I think this might complete the solution

Comment: You can use `fillna`. See the edit.

Comment: Hi @not_speshal, I've amended my question slightly, because now I've come across a scenario in my project where the first row has missing information. The current solution does not work anymore :(

Can you please kindly help me with the updated question??! I would be forever grateful if you could kindly provide a solution!!

Comment: @Sultan - Use `bfill` and `ffill`. Edited my answer. Also for future reference, please be fair and create new posts for new questions.